# Заставить % (процент) в Vim работать с BEGIN/END

Tags: delphi, pascal, vim, oberon

*Vim* позволяет перемещаться между открывающей и закрывающей
скобкой с помощью клавиши <kbd>%</kbd>.  Есть ли способ заставить этот
механизм работать с парами `BEGIN` и `END`
в паскале, дельфи, и обероне?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В современную поставку *Vim* входит модуль `matchit`,
который как раз для этого и предназначен.  Включается так:

```
" Include matchit for better matching.
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

Это надо добавить в ваш `vimrc`.